# Не могу заблокировать доступ пользователей к ресурсу по IP (iptables DROP)

Tags: iptables

**eth0** - интернет
**eth1** - локальная сеть (*192.168.0.0/24*)

Не могу заблокировать доступ пользователей к ресурсу по IP (**13.107.4.50**) (*Ubuntu server 14.04*):
Блокирую следующим образом:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 13.107.4.50 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -s 13.107.4.50 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 13.107.4.50 -j DROP
```

тем не менее у клиента и пинги проходят, и по веб могу открыть, не понимаю, почему не блокирует. вывод **iptables -L -v -n**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 47 packets, 3769 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       13.107.4.50          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       13.107.4.50          0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       13.107.4.50          0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 649 packets, 234K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 53 packets, 5245 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Одного DROP было бы достаточно, нет смысла его 3 раза добавлять. Вы пытаетесь закрыть доступ к самой машине на которой это делаете или для трафика проходящего сквозь машину ?  Если сквозь машину - то почему блочите входящие с того ip пакеты, он же и так никуда внутрь сам не попадет, было бы логичнее блокировать пакеты _на него_ (-d). А если блочите адресованное машине (вы же в INPUT пишите, он только для самой машины) - то это должно было бы отработать

Comment: @Mike учитывая наличие двух сетевых интерфейсов, моя телепатия подсказывает мне что речь идет о настройке правил на шлюзе, а не на сервере и не на клиенте

Comment: @PavelMayorov Не люблю я телепатию. надо же проверить что спрашивающий готов идти на контакт. Да и часто в вопросах 90% текста вообще к вопросу не относятся

Comment: да, всё правильно, хотелось бы блокировать на уровне шлюза

Comment: то есть блокировать определенный трафик, проходящий через шлюз к пользователям в локальной сети

Answer (score 1):

INPUT - это входящие пакеты, те которые идут непосредственно к вам. Вам же нужна цепочка FORWARD

Ну и все-таки лучше дропать пакеты не идущие от сервера, а идущие к серверу (-d вместо -s)